# Customize Logout using FBLoginView

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm putting together an iOS app and I'm using the FBLoginView as explained here. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-facebook-login-sdk/

I've now got a working app that displays a Login button and after logging out it becomes a Logout button. Obviously this isn't a realistic implementation of a Logout button. On login I'm segueing to a Tab Bar controller and I have a More tab on which I want to display a number of further options and a Logout option (exactly as the Facebook iOS app does).

My question is - can I hook a Logout menu option to fire the Logout that is handled by FBLoginViewDelegate and segue back to the Login view or do I have to manually implement login and logout using the FBSession class?

Comment: did you end up using custom Facebook UI flow or FBLoginView? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your own UI for login and logout, Forget FBLoginView and create action of your own login button and put the code below:

```
     [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"]
                                          allowLoginUI:YES
                                     completionHandler:
        ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

            if (error) {

                 // error

             }else {

                // user logged in
             }
         }];

    }
```

To logout, you just need to clear fb session and access token.